# Hibernate UniqueConstraint

Tags: java, hibernate

For example I have some entity like:

```
@Entity
public class WorkingScheduleOverride implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @Column
    private Date validFrom;

    @Column
    private Date validThru;

    @Column
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Date date;
```

To check that the entity is unique by field **date** I added **(unique = true)**. This works fine, but only if not to use "closable" approach to entities. It is for the cases if you want keep track the history of these objects. So I'm using 'validThru' field to specify till what time the entity is valid.

So my question is: is it possible by using any custom validations/annotations to check on uniqueness **ONLY VALID** entities `(validThru == null || validThru < new Date())`.

Incorrect data in database (two records has the same date and both are valid):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id  |version    |timestamp  |valid_from |valid_thru |date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |null       |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |null       |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Correct data in database (two records has the same date but second record is invalid):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id  |version    |timestamp  |valid_from |valid_thru |date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |null       |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |2012-06-01 |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Incorrect data in database (two records has the same date and both are valid, second record becomes invalid only 1th of January 2014):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id  |version    |timestamp  |valid_from |valid_thru |date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |null       |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2   |1          |2012-01-01 |2012-01-01 |2014-01-01 |2013-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: See if this is of any help for you scenario - http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Comment: Hi Sashi, it's impossible to do with validator. I can google and interested only who really already tackled with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question but.

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void checkEntity() {
    if ( validThru != null && validThru.getTime() > new Date().getTime() ) {
        throw new SomeException("Invalid entity");
    }
}
```

may do the job.

---

When you use `unique=true` the constraint is not at the code level, it is at the db level. If you want to ensure more advanced constraints, create a trigger that will reject the inserts and updates.

If a trigger can't be coded, you have to enforce your entity consistency with applicative code. Create a service with a `save(entity)` that will reject the bad entities with an exception.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, you didn't understand the problem. The question about UniqueConstraint with condition. Before saving to database you need to be sure that date is unique in this table but you need to check only entries in table where validThru != null && validThru < now. You are checking only part of it, and there is no sense in it.

Comment: In my opinion it's not possible to handle this with annotations. Or you'll need to create a custom BeanValidation constraint that will be able to check the records in database. You'd rather ensure your conditions with applicative code directly instead of trying to use annotations

Comment: It's easy way to handle this, but it is very nasty solution as I need to create extra layer to check 'those' entities on extra condition before saving it and create separately db contraint to the database, so potentially there could appear incosistency if someone forget to add this constraint to both places

Answer (score 0):

Instead of date,You can use TimeStamp.and unique column constraint on verion and id.So that any of the situation Your record could unique.
                                    Another way you can use  status as a column Where praticular record Valid-V and Invalid -I.you can show only valid or  invalid records based on the selection

Comment: Hi Ravi,I think you didn't understand the gist of the problem